# Rust deserialization: converting vector of bytes to hashset of uuid

Tags: rust

My goal is to
serialize (`HashSet<Uuid>` -> `Vec<u8>`)
and deserialize (`&[u8]` -> `HashSet<Uuid>`)
hashset of uuids.

I have following serialization:

```
fn serialize(set: HashSet<Uuid>) -> Vec<u8>{
  set.into_iter().map(|x| x.as_bytes()).collect()
}
```

My tries on writing on deserialization ended up on something like this, when I knew exact number of uuids:

```
fn clone_into_array<A, T>(slice: &[T]) -> A
            where A: Sized + Default + std::convert::AsMut<[T]>,
                  T: Clone
        {
            let mut a = Default::default();
            <A as std::convert::AsMut<[T]>>::as_mut(&mut a).clone_from_slice(slice);
            a
        }
```

```
fn deserialize(data: &[u8]){
    let first_uuid = Uuid::from_bytes(clone_into_array(&data[0..16]))
    ...

}
```

Questions:
Is my serialization even correct?

How can I deserialize from  `&[u8]` back to `HashSet<Uuid>` if I know it was previously serialized using `serialize` function if I don't know exact set size?

Is my approach to deserialization correct or there is other, much cleaner approach?

Comment: The "cleaner approach" would probably be to use [serde](https://crates.io/crates/serde)

Comment: yeah, but at the moment I'm not allowed to use any external crates.

Comment: Is the serialize method even compiling?

Comment: It doesn't, because it has no reason to. For some reason I thought it does, probably didn't save file before compilation, rookie mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your serialization is incorrect, as it tries to collect a `Vec<u8>` from a `Iterator<Item = &[u8; 16]>`. You can instead fold the iterator and extend a `Vec` over the slices. For deserialization, you know each `Uuid` will take up 16 bytes, so you should use `chunks_exact` to iterate over that and collect into a hashset:

```rust
fn serialize(set: HashSet<Uuid>) -> Vec<u8>{
    set.into_iter().fold(Vec::new(), |mut acc, v| {
        acc.extend_from_slice(v.as_bytes());
        acc
    })
}

fn deserialize(bytes: &[u8]) -> HashSet<Uuid> {
    bytes.chunks_exact(16).map(Uuid::from_slice).collect::<Result<_, _>>().unwrap()
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2d7956eb6c6c4ce1d3447df2835e4ddc)

Comment: It would be better to use `Vec::with_capacity(set.len() * 16)` instead of `Vec::new()` since GUIDs always has same length.